# Javascript unable to apply toFixed() to a function

Tags: javascript, function, tofixed

I have made a compounding calculator function and I am unable to apply toFixed() to it. What I basically want to do is apply toFixed(2) in order to get just two digits after the decimal. Here comes the code thank you very much in advance.

```
const compound = function () {
  const value1 = document.getElementById("value1").value;
  const value2 = document.getElementById("value2").value;
  const value3 = document.getElementById("value3").value;
  const compResult = document.querySelector(".result").innerHTML =
    value1 * value2 ** value3;
  return compResult.toFixed(2);
};
```

```
const calcButton = document.querySelector(".calculate");
calcButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  compound();
});
```

Comment: Are you expecting the content of `.result` to be `compResult.toFixed(2)`?

Comment: Correct and it was not working but the solution below by Hao Wu works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

You need to get the `toFixed(2)` value first and then display it on `.result`. The text of `.result` only changes when you assign its content explicitly.

```js
const compound = function () {
    const value1 = document.getElementById("value1").value;
    const value2 = document.getElementById("value2").value;
    const value3 = document.getElementById("value3").value;
    const compResult = (value1 * value2 ** value3).toFixed(2); 
    document.querySelector(".result").innerText = compResult;
    return compResult;
};
```

Comment: no need to return anything since the returned value isn't used anyway :p

Comment: Just in case, don't want to modify the output of this function :S